# Argumentos de left_join (dplyr)

Tags: r, r-dplyr, dplyr

Hice esta unión:

```
left_join(TABLA_1,TABLA_2,by = c("Nombre_tabla1" = "Nombre_tabla2"))
```

La tabla TABLA_1 tiene 99 columnas y la tabla TABLA_2 162, y yo de quiero traer solo una columna de la tabla tabla_2, no todas.

Es decir, en mi union quiero una tabla de 100 columnas y no una de 260 como lo hace

Hay algun argumento que se pueda utilizar para decirle a left_join que solo traiga una columna seleccionada? o ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con select()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, al menos desde un `left_join()`, pero si puedes preseleccionar las columnas de la tabla 2 de antemano:

```
left_join(TABLA_1,
          TABLA_2 %>%
              select(id, columna_de_interes),
          by = c("id" = "id"))
```